# Android View Pager which shows a hint of next child

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I want to tweak the original View Pager which shows a hint of next child.. see the image below:

[image]

I tried creating my own ViewPager which extends the original View Pager but i was unable to make it work.

I would really appreciate if you can point me towards any tutorial or library which does this or something similar.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you try setting the page width in the adapter for the view pager? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html#getPageWidth(int)

Comment: In PagerAdapter, there is an option to get the PageWidth but there is no option to set it.

Comment: Are you using a custom pager adapter. Try extending PagerAdapter and overriding the getPageWidth() method.  Try returning page width = 0.8f .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try extending the `pager adapter` - 
Override the `getPageWidth` method.

```
    @Override
    public float getPageWidth(int position) {
        return 0.8f; // 1f means 100 percent
    }
```